# How to validate multiple preselected checkbox with angular 8 reactive form

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have few checkboxes whose values are coming from loop,Here I am validating those checkboxes using reactive form.My validation is atleast one checkboxes should be selected.when I check and uncheck the checkbox validation is working fine,but when my all checkboxes are already preselected and click submit,even though its showing empty message.Is there any solution for it.Here is the code below.

### home.component.html

```
<div>
<p>Form 1</p>
<form [formGroup]="registerForm">
<div *ngFor="let grpdata of statusdata">
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="title" value="{{grpdata.groupid}}" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.title.errors }">{{grpdata.groupname}}<br>

</div>
<div *ngIf="submitted && f.title.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.title.errors.required">Title is required</div>
                    </div>
<button type="submit" (click)="getSelectedVal()">Click here</button>
 </form>
</div>

<div>
<p>Form 2</p>
<form [formGroup]="editForm">
<input type="textbox" disabled formControlName="edithidden" [(ngModel)]="hello" class="form-control"><br>
<div *ngFor="let grpdata of statusdata">
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="edittitle" [checked]=true value="{{grpdata.groupid}}" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted1 && g.edittitle.errors }">{{grpdata.groupname}}<br>


</div>
<div *ngIf="submitted1 && g.edittitle.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="g.edittitle.errors.required">Title is required</div>
                    </div>
<button type="submit" (click)="editSelectedVal()">Click here</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    submitted = false;
    submitted1 = false;
  getListData: any;
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  editForm: FormGroup;
  statusdata: any;
  constructor(private commonserviceService: CommonserviceService,private formBuilder: FormBuilder)
  {
      this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            title: [false, Validators.requiredTrue],
     });
     this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
             edittitle: [false, Validators.requiredTrue],
             edithidden: new FormControl()
     });

  }

  ngOnInit() {

      this.statusdata = [{"groupid":1,"groupname":"project1"},{"groupid":2,"groupname":"project2"},{"groupid":3,"groupname":"project3"}];

  }
   get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }
   get g() { return this.editForm.controls; }
 getSelectedVal(){

     this.submitted = true;

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }
console.log('submitted');   
 }
 editSelectedVal(){

     this.submitted1 = true;

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.editForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }
console.log('submitted edit');  
 }
}
```

Comment: can you check the value of `this.edittitle.value`?

Comment: No its showing error

Comment: Alright, can you please create a stackblitz? So we can test your code and see errors?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqjqdg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: you seem to only have one form group, you need one for every group you have.

Comment: First one is working but I need help for second one

Comment: It's all **Wrong**. you can not mixed formGroup and [(ngModel)], or [checked] it's a terrible code. Really, re-think. The questions you need make is: What data we need? what data you get?. Don't put the cart before the horse. First imagine an object. This object can be, e.g. {tittle:'',projects:[true,true,false]} or {title:'',projects:[1,3,4]}. When you know what object you can mannage, create the form

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="edittitle" [checked]=true...
```

You shouldn't try to set the value from outside of the form. You never know when it is actually attached. When you want to have the checkbox to be preselected use the form value instead.

```
this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
             edittitle: [true, Validators.requiredTrue], // true here, you had false here
             edithidden: new FormControl()
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used your concept but here I need to select all checkboxes to submit the form,but my requirement is atleast one selected to submit the form

Comment: Are you maybe looking for Cross-Field Validation? https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-reactive-forms-1

Comment: You can check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqjqdg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts  I have created a demo. Here I need help on second form

Comment: You are trying to use the same FormGroup several time. You will need to create a FormArray and push a FormGroup like `editForm` as often as you have a group in `statusData`. Please inform yourself about FormArrays and how to use them dynamically.